# Force Jade to not interpret plain text

Tags: pug

I'm trying to get Jade to not interpret part of my template, which according to the docs should be possible using a pipe or a dot (see http://jade-lang.com/reference/plain-text/).

What I see instead is that Jade does interpret piped html instead of just passing it through. So for example this template:

```
div.controls
  | <select id="someid" anotherProp>
  | </select>
```

Will generate the following HTML:

```
<div class="controls">
  <select id="someid" anotherprop=""></select>
</div>
```

Instead of:

```
<div class="controls">
  <select id="someid" anotherProp></select>
</div>
```

Notice that "anotherprop" was lower cased and a ="" was added. After searching I'm not even sure Jade is able of true plain text ...

**Context**
This example is simplified, I'm trying to include Mustache templates in the generated HTML for use in a single-page app. For example, the "anotherProp" above is in my actual code "{{#disable}}disabled{{/disable}}" but it gets transformed in garbage by Jade. I found a workaround which is to not use "<" and ">" in the "plain text" parts of the Jade template and use placeholders instead (I use the corresponding HTML entities), then replace these entities by Javascript before rendering the Mustache template. This is way too ugly for me to be satisfied.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, the issue was actually not with Jade but with the tools I used to look at the contents. Both the Chrome dev tools (Elements panel) and jQuery's html() function do not output the exact HTML but can modify it, since they rely on innerHTML (see http://api.jquery.com/html/). To make it worse the exact innerHTML behavior depends on the browser. Jade was doing its job normally.

The -almost- clean way to extract Mustache (or any other language) template from generated HTML and make sure it's not modified by the browser is to encapsulate the whole code in HTML comments `<!--` and `-->`, then strip the comments after retrieving the template. That way you get the best of both worlds: expressive Jade preprocessing and in-document Mustache templates.